# DRF, how to communicate interface parameters for api endpoints to other programmers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

For instance I have the following endpoint, and want to let our client programmers know that he needs to send `email/password1/password2` and he would get UserSerializer format data.

How can I effectively let others know the api specification without forcing him to drill down the code?

```
 @list_route(methods=['post'], permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny])
 def register(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
     from django.contrib.auth import login as login_base

     User = get_user_model()

     email = request.data.get('email')
     password1 = request.data.get('password1')
     password2 = request.data.get('password2')

     ... 


     user.send_activation_email(request=request)
     # login_base(request, user)
     serializer = self.get_serializer(user)

     return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a library for automated API schema generation.

[`drf-yasg`](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg) is one of the most popular libraries for this purpose in DRF, here is an example photo of what you can achieve with it:
[image: drf-yasg API docs example]

Everything related to it is very well described in the GitHub itself, so you may give it a try.